# Docusign API - document from template sets wrong signature position

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign API to send a document for signature via a template I've created manually in my account. 
The Signature and Date Signed tags in my template use text anchors within the document and are positioned 325 from left and 882 from top of page. If I send a document using this template via the web interface the signature boxes are placed perfectly.

When I use the API however, the position of the signature boxes are wrong, all offset horizontally by about -200mm and vertically +10mm.

I assumed that if I call a template with name, email and rolename the end result would be identical to sending via the web interface. 
I know I could add a tags block with position but I don't want to have to replicate template parameters.

```
{
"status"        : "sent",
"templateId"    : "TEMPLATE-ID",
"templateRoles" : 
    [
        {
        "name"         : "John Smith",
        "email"        : "John@Smith.com",
        "roleName"     : "First Life",
        }
        $Life2Block
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try removing and reattaching the tags to the Template. It should be the same experience via API or console with envelopes created from Templates.

Comment: @AndrewWilson I've tried that but still the same.
Interestingly when I add the tags in console, place my Sign Here where I want it, then edit the tag for the anchor text, it jumps about 200 to the right. So I move it back where I want it. If I DON'T move it back after it jumps, then the API generated version is certainly lined up correct horizontally, maybe 5mm below the anchor text.

Comment: Hmmph, is this template something that you can share the exported XML (no company or personal information in it, etc?). I'm still thinking it's an issue with the template itself

Comment: @AndrewWilson The actual template is sensitive so I created a two page test template and recreated my issue. 
This template has two signature tabs for one signer and DateSigned. 
If I create a doc using the web console, all is good. Via API (with or without a merged doc) the tabs shift.   
http://wikisend.com/download/368938/SFA_Doc_Test_StackOverflow.xml   
I should add that the json my API call makes, has no position information, I'm relying on the template for that.

Comment: The signed doc looks like this.  
http://wikisend.com/download/100246/test_doc_signed.pdf

Comment: It sounds like perhaps the API request ignores the anchor text offset.  I'm pretty sure tab placement is slightly different depending on where the anchor text/offset is specified (in a template, custom tag, or API call).  You might be running into that.

Comment: I've now spoken to someone in DocuSign support on this issue.  
Apparently I'm not doing anything wrong, it seems that it's not possible to use a pre-existing template and expect it to place tags based on anchors, which seems to me to be a bug. Surely the whole point of anchors in templates is to position signatures?  
Having to rethink DocuSign as a solution now, which seems kind of ridiculous over a minor bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you have to have 2 sets of templates that use relative anchor positioning; one for the API, and one for the web interface.  The API has a slightly different reference point than the web interface.  From your tests, you have seen this fact.  My tests have shown that the API will position the tab over the beginning of the matching text, whereas the web interface positions the tab over the end of the matching text.

My solution is to code my API script to overwrite the tab offsets set in the template.  The following snippet is under the template node:

```
"recipients": {
"signers":[{
    "email": a@b.com,
        "name":"John Smith",
        "recipientId":"1",
        "roleName":"Signer 1",
             "tabs":{
             "signHereTabs":[
                    {
                     "tabLabel":"Signature 3",
                     "anchorString":"Applicants Signature*",
                     "anchorYOffset": "0",
                     "anchorXOffset": "120"
                              }]
              }
         }]
  }
```

Using anchorXOffset and anchorYOffset, you can trial-and-error what the API version of your offsets should be.  If you are confident in the measurements in real life, you can use the characteristic "anchorUnits" for "inches", "mms", or "cms".  However, I've had PDFs that did not correlate well to physical units.  The default anchorUnit is "pixels".